# Java thread scheduling separation

Tags: java, string, multithreading, scheduling, runnable

The object of the program is to send three strings to three separate threads and have them print out each string character by character. I want a blank line in between each input string but I'm not sure where to put each thread into a waiting state or stop it so the the output varies. Most of the time it's a combo of the strings jumbled up, sometimes one separates and comes out neatly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Threader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        String str2 = scan.nextLine();
        String str3 = scan.nextLine();

        Thread A = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str));
        A.start();

        Thread B = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str2));
        B.start();

        Thread C = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str3));
        C.start();
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    String str, str2, str3;
    public MyRunnable(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to achieve a specific separation you will certainly have to use wait/notify or some species of semaphore.

Comment: I don't get it, you want each thread to print the String, one character per line, but you don't want another thread to print will there is one doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, spells out and separates each strings with spaces in between them. Funny thing is my teacher just wanted them to start at the same time and output all jumbled just to demonstrate a race condition. :p But here it is, a couple while loops with sleeps. Ugly but it works

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Threader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 3 lines...Suuuuh dude");

    /*
     * Strangs
     */
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    String str2 = scan.nextLine();
    String str3 = scan.nextLine();

    /*
     * Intantiate threads holding runnable objects
     */
    Thread A = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str));
    Thread B = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str2));
    Thread C = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str3));

    A.start();
    // B.start();
    // C.start();

    /*
     * try { A.join(); B.join(); C.join();
     * 
     * } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     * e.printStackTrace(); }
     */

    /*
     * Uncomment While() Loops To Eliminate race conditions (Threads will
     * sleep if previous one is Alive(Won't fight for cpu))
     */

    while (A.isAlive()) {
        try {

            B.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("\n");
        } // end try
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch
    } // end while

    B.start();
    while (B.isAlive()) {
        try {
            C.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("\n");
        } // end try
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch
    } // end while
    C.start();
}// main METHOD

}// Threader CLASS
```

//Class w/ Runnable Int.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

String str, str2, str3;

public MyRunnable(String str) {
    this.str = str;
    this.str2 = str2;
    this.str3 = str3;

}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        try {
            // sleep 1 ms before printing next char
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // for
    System.out.println("end" + str);
}// run

}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Threader {
    public Threader(String str, String str2, String str3) {
        Thread A = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str));
        Thread B = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str2));
        Thread C = new Thread(new MyRunnable(str3));

        A.start();
        B.start();
        C.start();
    }

    public synchronized void printString(String str) {
        for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(c);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        String str2 = scan.nextLine();
        String str3 = scan.nextLine();

        new Threader(str, str2, str3);
    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private String str;

        public MyRunnable(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            printString(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? Doesn't this code do what the OP asked for?